# select id, table1.column1 + table2.column2 as total from table1 join table2. what if table2.column2 has no value?

Tags: mysql

help. T_T

table 1

```
+---------------+---------+-------------------+
| allowances_id | desc_id | column1           |
+---------------+---------+-------------------+
|             1 |       1 | 64055.35594866848 |
|             2 |       4 | 55627.97197247496 |
|             3 |       6 | 55627.97197247496 |
|             4 |       7 | 55627.97197247496 |
|             5 |       8 | 55627.97197247496 |
|             6 |       9 | 55627.97197247496 |
|             7 |       2 | 50293.50333209634 |
+---------------+---------+-------------------+
```

table 2

```
+---------+-------+
| desc_id | total |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | 18150 |
|       4 | 18150 |
|       6 | 18150 |
|       7 | 18150 |
|       8 | 18150 |
|       9 | 18150 |
+---------+-------+
```

i want table1.column1 + table2.total

table1 (desc_id has a value of 2 in table2 desc_id has no value of 2 so basically the result should be column1 + 0.00

Comment: Please provide what you already tried to do and why it isn't working.

Comment: don't be afraid to experiment `select 599+null` ... it won't bite you.

Comment: also an update with an inner join pattern won't join for id 2. So the update won't happen.

Comment: somethings wrong about my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.column1 + COALESCE(t2.column2, 0)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: what if t2 returns an empty set? then the query you post will return also an empty set

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I miss understood. If you have explicitly added not null for the column while creating then the empty and null values should be stored as 0.

Comment: both are the same type. what if the column from table 2 returns an empty set, i want the value to be 0 so that the equation still works. cause in these set up it will return empty set

Comment: Can you please tell the creation command of tables, also the insertion command.

Comment: already done. tnx anyway. what i did in code is that i use join not left join

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL in sql if you think your value can be null also.

```
table1.column2 + ISNULL(table2.column2,0)
```

Comment: the value is not null. its an empty set.. like no ids match to table1 so basicaly none. 

if the other column returns an empty set it shoud be set default to 0 so that the value in column1 will be the value of equation

Comment: then you should use left join